# At what temperature will the hydrogen molecules escape from earth's surface?

Tags: escape-velocity

At what temperature will the hydrogen molecules escape from the earth's surface?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/302555/why-doesnt-hydrogen-gas-exist-in-earths-atmosphere

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equations $v_{rms} = \sqrt {\frac {3k_bT} {m}}$ where $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant and $m$ is the mass of a molecule of $H_2$ and $v_{esc} = \sqrt {\frac {2GM} {r}}$ where $G$ is the gravitational constant and $M$ and $r$ are the mass and radius of the Earth. Equate the two equations to solve for velocity.